# Bootstrap not working in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

**Global.asax:**

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            MappingConfig.RegisterMaps();
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
```

**Bundleconfig:**

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap").Include(
        "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
        "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-default">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.naam)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.beschrijving)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{ var i = 1;}
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.werkvormen)
            {
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">@i</th>
                    <td>@item.naam</td>
                    <td>@item.beschrijving</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

So I'm trying to use bootstrap but it's not doing anything on my page. "using System.Web.Optimization;" is added and I get no build errors/errors of any kind. So it should be working but it isn't, why?

Comment: Try adding the class col-xs-4 to all of your table headers and td.

Comment: Are you actually loading bootstrap onto the specific page?  You should have `@Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap")` in the header section of your layout page.

Comment: @PhillipXT Oh... I assumed that's what bundleconfig does for me. Works now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bundle.config file does nothing but group files together.  They are not all automatically added to every page - you have to specify which group(s) you want in your layout page.

To specify which group of files to use, add this to the header section of your layout page:

```
@Styles.Render("~/styles/User")
```

This way, you can create a second group called `"~/styles/Admin"`, and the two sets of files won't interfere with each other.

Same goes with javascript files:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a complement to PhilipXt answer's, because this was what realy worked in my situation, I was trying to render in asp.net api some views, and because of that, i found this answer.

If everything is right with wwwroot folder, the line that is missing is:
[image]

So you could seek on the following site to check everything:
[Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0)